# High ping latency when playing online games

Tags: networking, dns, ping, latency, steam

I switched to a WISP (fixed wireless) internet provider to improve internet speeds. I now have up to 30 MBPS. When playing multiplayer online games ping latency shoots up to 500+ ms. Why does the latency increase? I have noticed that if I am simultaneously downloading a large file and playing an online game the latency issues disappears. Is there a DNS issue with my new provider? Is there an issue with the game servers? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: DNS  issues would not affect ping times. It could affect time to the first ping, but after that initial DNS lookup it would no longer affect it. Have you tried pinging the game server itself?

Comment: If your computer is particularly underpowered it could be programs vying for CPU time making the ping look bad.

Comment: Mobile networks use a shared medium: the air. And to serve multiple users each user gets certain time slots. It looks like the game data rate is too low (from the perspective of the network) so that you only 2-4 times per second get a slot, hence in the mean time the data gets collected and then sent in bulk. For downloads this works, for gaming this is bad. When your large download is running you produce more traffic and get more time slots (if they are free). May you can talk with the operator of the network if there is smth. like a `fastpath` option available (send/receive data more often).

Comment: Do you know the make and model of the device that connects you to the WISP?